# PhoneGap Build inAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build, inappbrowser

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the inApp Browser in Phonegap Build. My code looks like this:
Javascript:

```
function appBrowse(url) {
         var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
    }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="" onClick="javascript:appBrowse('http://www.naturefund.de/erde/co2_rechner/co2_rechner_nahrung.html')">CO2 Rechner</a>
```

Is there anything else I need? I feel like I am missing something very basic.
I added the plugin to my config.xml

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. In the end, just reinstalling the App worked. I assume that certain changes in the config.xml (like whitelisting a url, or adding a plugin) need a complete reinstall instead of just an update via Hydration.

Answer (score 1):

Which Cordova version do you use? If on version 3 did you add the plugin code to the project as well with `$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser` ?
Read up here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

Comment: thanks for the answer. since I am using phonegap Build (v. 3.1.0), I was under the impression, I don't need any command line tools.

Comment: Ah in that case I can't really help since I don't use phonegap build. Still could be that the add plugin command changes some other things as well I'm not sure. Try it out with phonegap instead of cordova as command.